# I can t use this list and i have this problem

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with this List

the error said : he default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled

```
class Geometry {
      late List<List> coordinates  ;
      late String type;
    
      Geometry({required this.coordinates, required this.type});
    
      Geometry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        if (json['coordinates'] != null) {
          coordinates = new List<List>();
          json['coordinates'].forEach((v) { coordinates.add(new List.fromJson(v)); });
        }
        type = json['type'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (this.coordinates != null) {
          data['coordinates'] = this.coordinates.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
        }
        data['type'] = this.type;
        return data;
      }
    }
```

Comment: use https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable to automatically generate your class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the pre-null-safety operations

```
var foo = List<int>();  // Now error
var bar = List<int>(n); // Now error
var baz = List<int>(0); // Now error
```

use the following:

```
var foo = <int>[];           // Always the recommended way.
var bar = List.filled(1, 0); // Not filled with `null`s.
var baz = List<int>.empty();
```

Comment: but i also have a problem when i call List.fromJason()

Comment: This solution may fix the problem. Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015688/flutter-errors-when-trying-to-save-json-array-to-list